# How can I know where does a message in rabbitMQ send from?

Tags: rabbitmq

When we using rabbitMQ topic exchange, We can send a message at everywhere. And our project is very large, when I receive a message, and we found there is a problem in the message and we want to modify the message at where it was sent. But it is hardly be found where the message was sent.

Is there a method or a command tool in rabbitMQ to find out where that message sent from.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few information that you can take using the `envelop`, as `exchange`, `delivery_tag`, `routing_key` :

```
Consumer consumer_a = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                    throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
              long delivery_tag =   envelope.getDeliveryTag();
              String exchange_from =   envelope.getExchange();
              String routing_key =  envelope.getRoutingKey();

             }
        };
```

if you need more info you can use the `headers` to add custom information as:

```
  var properties = new BasicProperties();
  properties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  properties.Headers.Add("mysender_user", "my_server");
  properties.Headers.Add("my_custom_info", "my_info");

  channel.BasicPublish(ExchangeName, "", properties, message);
```